# Set recursion depth

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently facing the problem that I have to do an operation in every first dir "layer" of a directory.

I have a folder with thousands of sub dirs, I would just dor a for loop with /r but the problem is, those sub-dirs contain more sub-dirs an I don't want to go into those.
For visualization:

```
Root Dir
----Sub-Dir 1
--------Sub-Dir 1 of Sub-Dir 1
--------Sub-Dir 2 of Sub-Dir 1
----Sub-Dir 2
--------Sub-Dir 1 of Sub-Dir 2
--------Sub-Dir 2 of Sub-Dir 2
----Sub-Dir 3
--------Sub-Dir 1 of Sub-Dir 3
--------Sub-Dir 2 of Sub-Dir 3
```

and I only want to go into the first "layer" Sub-Dir 1,2,3 etc. and don't touch the sub-sub-dirs of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need are nested FOR /D statements (total of 2).

```
@echo off
pushd "rootDir"
call :doCommands
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  pushd "%%F"
  call :doCommands
  for /d %%F in (*) do (
    pushd "%%F"
    call :doCommands
    popd
  )
  popd
)
popd
exit /b

:doCommands
echo processing "%cd%"
exit /b
```

**EDIT**

Here is a generic solution that allows you to specify the root folder as arg1 (%1) and how many levels down to go as arg2 (%2).

```
@echo off
set currentLevel=0
set maxLevel=%2
if not defined maxLevel set maxLevel=0

:procFolder
pushd %1
echo processing "%cd%"
if %currentLevel% lss %maxLevel% (
  for /d %%F in (*) do (
    set /a currentLevel+=1
    call :procFolder "%%F"
    set /a currentLevel-=1
  )
)
popd
```

Comment: And how do I get in the first Sub-Dir layer?
I may wasn't that clear about it, edited the last sentence of the question :)

Comment: @PaulGreen - Just add one more FOR /D loop. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PaulGreen - I've added another option that allows you to set the max depth. Very clean and simple.